# Why does Django REST Framework Router break query parameter filtering?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-filters

In the [Django REST Framework Tutorial quickstart](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#urls), views are added to the default router:

```
// project/urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
```

My project layout is

```
project/
    stuffs/
```

I include the stuffs application in the default router:

```
router.register(r'stuffs', views.StuffViewSet)
```

The `stuffs/` endpoint is then nicely listed in the API Root list of endpoints:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "users": "http://localhost:8000/users/",
    "groups": "http://localhost:8000/groups/",
    "stuffs": "http://localhost:8000/stuffs/"
}
```

A `Stuff` object has a relationship to a owner model class and to filter for objects belonging to a certain owner, I intend to use a request such as:

`stuffs/?owner_id=abc`

In order to do so, and here is where I'm not sure if it is correct, I introduced an `urls.py` configuration in the `stuffs` app:

```
// stuffs/urls.py
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    path('stuffs/', stuffs_views.StuffList.as_view()),
    path('stuffs/<int:pk>/', stuffs_views.StuffDetail.as_view()),
    re_path(r'^stuffs/(?P<owner_id>.+)$', stuffs_views.StuffsList.as_view())
])
```

using the below StuffsList class based view:

```
class StuffList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StuffSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Stuff.objects.all()
        owner_id = self.request.query_params.get('owner_id')
        if owner_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(owner__owner_id=owner_id)
        return queryset
```

I'm pretty sure this view is correct, because when I remove the View Set from the default router, the query works.

However, when the viewset is registered in the default router, when requesting `stuffs/?owner_id=abc` the filter is not applied.

I would like to have the viewset in the list of endpoints but at the same time be able to filter using the query parameter. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `StuffViewSet`? Depending on that you might need to override the `list` method of `StuffViewSet` and put your filter there.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying with `short_id` ? Anyway Try this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Stuff.objects.all()
    owner_id = self.request.query_params.get('owner_id')
    if owner_id is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(owner__short_id=int(owner_id))
    return queryset
```

Comment: It's supposed to be `owner_id` everywhere (`short_id` was a remains of the original code), I correct it.

Comment: Without the `r'^stuffs/(?P<owner_id>.+)$'` route, the filtering doesn't work anymore.